# upowerd hogging CPU in Lubuntu 20.04, how can I stop it?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu

Mouse movement become laggy within last days for me.

On checking `top` I noticed `upowerd` often taking 15%, 27% of CPU. It is seems unreasonable given [its function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPower).

I want, at least as test, to stop it. `killall upowerd` failed to have lasting effect, it reappeared.

upowerd man page has

> Users or administrators should never need to start this daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) whenever an application calls into the org.freedesktop.UPower service.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemctl disable upower` seems to be stopping it until reboot